# Epilog doesn't work with ListLogPlot

Tags: plotting

We have data series:

```
data1={{0., 5.02512*10^-10}, {0.06668, 2.99284*10^-8}, {0.13336,
 3.22116*10^-8}, {0.20004, 2.58191*10^-8}, {0.26672,
 1.99125*10^-7}, {0.3334, 1.21646*10^-8}, {0.40008,
3.35916*10^-7}, {0.46676, 3.79768*10^-7}, {0.53344,
1.02102*10^-7}, {0.60012, 1.17535*10^-6}, {0.6668,
 1.72507*10^-7}, {0.73348, 1.23789*10^-6}, {0.80016,
 1.9808*10^-6}, {0.86684, 1.39616*10^-7}, {0.93352,
 4.60649*10^-6}, {1.0002, 1.39262*10^-6}, {1.06688,
 3.83127*10^-6}, {1.13356, 0.0000101002}, {1.20024,
 3.26005*10^-8}, {1.26692, 0.0000229263}, {1.3336,
0.0000144712}, {1.40028, 0.000020778}, {1.46696,
 0.000134013}, {1.53364, 4.94753*10^-6}, {1.60032,
 0.00250851}, {1.667, 0.00326501}, {1.73368, 0.0000968109}, {1.80036,
  0.000207831}, {1.86704, 7.79724*10^-6}, {1.93372,
  0.0000459028}, {2.0004, 0.0000321442}, {2.06708,
  2.43685*10^-6}, {2.13376, 0.0000276559}, {2.20044,
   3.87948*10^-6}, {2.26712, 9.62673*10^-6}, {2.3338,
  0.0000130072}, {2.40048, 1.53889*10^-7}, {2.46716,
  0.0000116171}, {2.53384, 3.36691*10^-6}, {2.60052,
  3.53838*10^-6}, {2.6672, 8.3132*10^-6}, {2.73388,
   2.36251*10^-8}, {2.80056, 6.58432*10^-6}, {2.86724,
  3.33096*10^-6}, {2.93392, 1.45936*10^-6}, {3.0006,
   6.35157*10^-6}, {3.06728, 2.69642*10^-7}, {3.13396,
  4.25243*10^-6}, {3.20064, 3.49319*10^-6}, {3.26732,
 5.50908*10^-7}, {3.334, 5.33684*10^-6}, {3.40068,
   6.86369*10^-7}, {3.46736, 2.92315*10^-6}, {3.53404,
    3.88476*10^-6}, {3.60072, 1.32685*10^-7}, {3.6674,
   4.88858*10^-6}, {3.73408, 1.2985*10^-6}, {3.80076,
   2.10915*10^-6}, {3.86744, 4.63201*10^-6}, {3.93412,
   9.45702*10^-10}, {4.0008, 4.94888*10^-6}, {4.06748,
   2.37468*10^-6}, {4.13416, 1.60386*10^-6}, {4.20084,
  6.40728*10^-6}, {4.26752, 1.82055*10^-7}, {4.3342,
  6.14228*10^-6}, {4.40088, 5.175*10^-6}, {4.46756,
   1.4092*10^-6}, {4.53424, 0.000013092}};
```

And we wish to have bellow command which drives us crazy:

```
ListLogPlot[{data1},
       Epilog -> {
     Style[Text["a", {2, 10^-6}], 11, Bold, Background -> White],
     Style[Text["b", {2, 10^-7}], 11, Bold, Background -> White],
     Style[Text["c", {2, 10^-9}], 11, Bold, Background -> White],
     Style[Text["d", {2, 10^-11}], 11, Bold, Background -> White]}
      ]
```

Comment: You can try with `ListLogPlot[{data1}, 
 Epilog -> {Style[Text["a", {2, 10^-6}], 11, Bold, 
     Background -> White], 
    Style[Text["b", {2, 10^-7}], 11, Bold, Background -> White], 
    Style[Text["c", {2, 10^-9}], 11, Bold, Background -> White], 
    Style[Text["d", {2, 10^-11}], 11, Bold, 
     Background -> White]} /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} -> {Log[x], 
    Log[y]}]`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `Epilog` option is not used by `ListLogPlot` directly. It is simply passed on to the `Graphics` expression returned by `ListLogPlot`.  The coordinates you use in `Epilog` are interpreted in the standard coordinate system, not in a special logarithmic one.  Thus you must transform your coodrinates manually.

Instead of `{2, 10^-7}` use `{2, Log[10^-7]}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
ListLogPlot[data1,
 Epilog -> 
  MapThread[Style[Text[#1, {##2}], 11, Bold, Background -> White] &,
   {{"a", "b", "c", "d"}, {2, 2, 2, 2}, Log[10 ^-{6, 7, 9, 11}]}],
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {10^-12, Automatic}}]
```

[image]